# Examples of smooth curves of genus $0$ and degree $d>2$.

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Can we provide a source of explicit examples ?

The degree assumption $d>2$ means that I would like to see examples which are not conics.

Answer (score 8):

The arithmetic genus of a curve $C\subset \mathbb P^2_k$ of degree $d$ is the number $p_a(C)=dim_k H^1(C, \mathcal O_C)$ and is equal to $\frac {(d-1)(d-2)}{2}$.
Thus that arithmetic genus is $\gt0$ for curves of degree $d\gt2$.
However that curve $C$ has a geometric genus too, equal to the arithmetic genus of the normalization $\tilde C$ : $p_g(C)=p_a(\tilde C)$.
Of course these genera coincide for normal (=nonsingular)  curves .

The geometric genus may be zero for curves of degree $d\gt0$ : for example the cusp $C$ given by $y^2z=x^3$ in $\mathbb P^2$ has geometric genus $0$, since its normalization is the projective line $\mathbb P^1$:$$\mathbb P^1=\tilde C\to C:(u:v) \mapsto (x=uv^2:y=v^3: z=u^3)      $$

**Edit: Addressing the competition**
The right honourable user 64494 in his answer below gives the interesting example of the projective plane curve $x^4+x^2yz+yz^3=0$ and reports that his mysterious friend *Maple* (not a registered user) has computed its geometric genus to be zero.
This is confirmed by our less mysterious friend Julius Plücker, alas deceased (1801-1868), who gave the formula (cf. [Seidenberg's book](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Elements_of_the_theory_of_algebraic_curv.html?id=EkbvAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) p.129 )$$p_g=\frac {(d-1)(d-2)}{2}  -\sum \frac {s_i(s_i-1)}{2}                 $$ for a plane projective curve having only singularities $P_i$  of  multiplicity $s_i$,  with distinct tangents   .
The curve $x^4+x^2yz+yz^3=0$ has as only singularity $(0:1:0)$, of multiplicity $3$,  with three distinct tangents $z=0,x\pm iy=0$. 
So the displayed formula yields $$p_g=\frac {(4-1)(4-2)}{2}  - \frac {3(3-1)}{2}  =0               $$  Plücker and *Maple* embrace each other across the centuries...

Comment: That's interesting but I am not sure this friend of yours, Julius, is a registered user.

Comment: Also, what kinda name is Julius ? Was he Roman or wha ?

Comment: Also I never knew that a smooth curve can have singularities of multiplicity $3$

Comment: 1) Julius is a German name, of Roman origin. 2) Of course a smooth curve cannot have a singularity: the curve referred to is not smooth. By the way, was it you who downvoted me?

Comment: No. Perhaps $Maple$ did ?

Comment: @Captain: yeah, probably. I always thought this was a suspicious, malicious character.

Comment: "This"? There a personality behind these calculations, it is not an object! I am afraid more downvotes will be awarded in the future on his/her behalf.

Comment: Dear Captain, there are such concepts as irony, sarcasm, derision, humour, parody, satire, mockery, persiflage...And  people immune to those concepts are welcome to reveal themselves and downvote me.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with philosophical endeavours of such nature and depth, therefore I will let $Maple$ know if I ever cross paths with him.

Answer (score 3):

A smooth projective plane curve of genus $0$ has to be either a line or a conic.

But the morphism $t \mapsto (t,t^2,t^3,\ldots,t^{d-1})$ (in affine coordinates)
embeds $\mathbb P^1$ into $\mathbb P^d$ as a smooth curve of degree $d$.  (The image
is called a [*rational normal curve of degree* $d$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_normal_curve).)

If you choose a generic projection from $\mathbb P^d$ to $\mathbb P^3$, the image
of a degree $d$ rational normal curve will be a rational curve of degree $d$ in $\mathbb P^3$.